# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'error' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I'm fairly new to React and I've been trying to create a SignUp page, however, I'm stuck in this error. Can someone give me any indication on what I should do in order to solve this error?

[image]

[image]

Signup Method:

```
//  = Action =
// Sign up
export const signup = user => {
    return fetch(
        `${API}/signup`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept:'application/json',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: It means that data is undefined. It has nothing to do with react. The promise returned from signup is probably not resolving a value, so data is undefined

Comment: Could you share your `signup` method ?

Comment: @Hurobaki, I've added the signup method

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite Signup method (ps: I only changed the .catch handler)

`

```js
// Sign up
export const signup = user => {
    return fetch(
        `${API}/signup`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept:'application/json',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(err => 
           console.log(err));
           return err;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap up your `fetch` logic inside a Promise to return a value to the caller.

```
export const signup = user => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(`${API}/signup`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept:'application/json',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsonData => resolve(jsonData))
        .catch(err => resolve({error: `something went wrong err : ${err}`}));
  })
}

signup(user).then(data => {
  if (data.error) {
    // handle error case 
  } else {
    // handle success case
  }
})
```

Now your `signup` method will return a value. Your `data` variable won't be `undefined` anymore.

I hope it helps, feel free to add comments or ask me more details